# Sending latitude and longitude coordinates to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a this function to grab the lat and long in my app delegate, and it's working fine:

```
- (void)newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location {

    // Store for later use
    self.lastKnownLocation = location;

    // Remove spinner from view
    for (UIView *v in [self.viewController.view subviews])
    {
        if ([v class] == [UIActivityIndicatorView class])
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Alert user
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Found" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Found physical location.  %f %f", self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude, self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];  

    currentLatitude = (self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"current latitude: %f",self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude);


    currentLongitude = (self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"current longitude: %f",currentLongitude);
}
```

However, I'm trying to send the currentLatitude and currentLongitude values to the top of the app delegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions section.  I'm trying to do this so I can pass those values to another viewController in which I have set up:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Can I send the currentLatitude and currentLongitude values to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you want to pass those coordinate values to another view controller. If thats the case u can make the `currentLatitude` and `currentLongitude` as class variables of the app delegate. Then when u call this function in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you can assign the values to these class variables. Then u can access these variables anywhere through an instance of the app delegate.

Note: You have to synthesize the variables if u want to access them outside the class.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a `currentLatitude` and `currentLongitude` in the second viewController?

You can use

```
- (void)newPhysicalLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    // your code here

    SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController setLatitude: currentLatitude andLongitude: currentLongitude];
}
```

or just

```
[viewController setCurrentLatitude: currentLatitude];
[viewController setCurrentLongitude: currentLongitude];
```

Comment: thanks, i did an implementation similar to this, and got it to work

Comment: Please accept and/or vote if the answer is helpful for you. Others might find this answer relevant to their questions. Thanks and you're welcome.